# Upgrading 32 bit to 64 bit (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am trying to upgrade from 32 bit to 64 bit of Windows 10 without loosing data. I looked up my processor specs and they mention that 64 bit is supported. So, I installed the installer to a Pen Drive an got it running. Once I get to the part for choosing the disk and partition, I cannot choose anything because Windows 10 x64 requires an GPT disk but the disks are MBR. Any tutorials I've followed don't have this issue. I tried to convert the disk with some external tools but they refuse to convert because GPT is not supported by 32 bit operating systems.

Is there a way to upgrade 32 bit windows 10 to 64 bit without data loss.

Comment: @DanielB It is a duplicate of that one indeed. Which Windows version doesn't matter. 32 to 64 bit is real the problem.

Comment: “I tried to convert the disk with some external tools but they refuse to convert because GPT is not supported by 32 bit operating systems.” - **This is absolutely false.**

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to upgrade 32 bit windows 10 to 64 bit without data
> loss.

Not exactly.

You have to back up all your data, documents, email and any favorites and like data that is important to you.

You then have to format (wipe clean) your machine and do a fresh install of Windows 10 64-bit.

That is the only way to do this.

Comment: Then why would the Win10 x64 bootable install CD/flash stick offer a choice of "Upgrade and keep files" vs clean install at all? Obviously they intended for this to be possible to do, even if they didn't make it a clean and intuitive process (the next screen says you can't do it while booted from the stick).

Comment: Upgrade and keep files is not related to changing from 32-bit to 64-bit or the other way around.